# I faced such problem in R could not find function "setup_twitter_oauth"

Tags: r

Error in setup_twitter_oauth("API_key, API_token, Access_token, Accses_token_secret") :
could not find function "setup_twitter_oauth"

I typed API Key and Secret, Bearer Token and Access Token and Secret  from the Twitter developer portal correctly, but the console looks like this

Comment: Google "setup_twitter_oauth" and try to find the package, install it.

Comment: You need `library(twitteR)` to make the function available.